# Is Boost Message Queues file Level Persistence?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

Is Boost Message Queues file Level Persistence?

In the boost IPC documentation It has mention that Message Queues are file or kernel level persistence.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/interprocess/some_basic_explanations.html

So my question is are they file level persistence means can survive the Restart or lasts in the memory if we restart also.

If they are kernel level persistence by default how can we make them file level persistence?

**Edit**: when I logged off my system and again logged in the queue was there and working fine but when I restarted the system the queue has removed , I am using Ubunutu  and want to implement a queue that can survive server crash how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

As the docs explain the distinction is implementation dependent.

Some platforms will have kernel support (and hence, "kernel level persistance" for shared IPC objects), some won't:

> As you can see, Boost.Interprocess defines some mechanisms with "Kernel or Filesystem" persistence. This is because POSIX allows this possibility to native interprocess communication implementations. One could, for example, implement shared memory using memory mapped files and obtain filesystem persistence (for example, there is no proper known way to emulate kernel persistence with a user library for Windows shared memory using native shared memory, or process persistence for POSIX shared memory, so the only portable way is to define "Kernel or Filesystem" persistence).

It is **not** something you can just switch.

What's more, it might not be what you are after (persistence is about the lifetime of the objects, not about the messages, AFAICT)

Comment: Thanks so if we make it as file level persistence then after restart the  object(M Queue) will be there but messages may not.